# reusing ssh key for ecryptfs-ed directory (ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ecryptfs

On a x86-64 laptop running [Ubuntu/Focal 20.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/) I have generated a `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public and  `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key with `ssh-keygen -b 4096` and a difficult to remember passphrase.

#### I would like to set-up some [ecryptfs](https://www.ecryptfs.org/) encrypted directory sharing the *same* ssh-managed passphrase.

That is, I just enter one passphrase using `ssh-add` and then would like to have access to that encrypted directory `/otherssd/encrypted-dir`

Is that possible, and then, how?

The `ecryptfs-utils` package has version `111-0ubuntu7`

The `openssh-client` package (providing `ssh-add`) has version `1:8.2p1-4`

It seems that [`sshfs`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) is overkill for that situation.... It is a remote encrypted file system, not a local one...

Comment: This seems unlikely. Disk encryption usually uses symmetric key encryption because it is stronger and, unlike public/private key encryption, it doesn't need digital signature(s).  Sshfs is not an encrypted file system. It's encrypted access to a remote file system which might not be encrypted on disk.